# Identify whether print dialog box closed or printing completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My requirement is to let the user print a document and update the database status. The user usually prints document as a PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF. I need to identify whether either user clicked the print button and saved the PDF or closed it without printing. Also, I need to redirect the user after a successful print.

I tried to add `element.onafterprint` event but it seems it returns the same response in both cases.

Also, with the above PDF printer, `element.onafterprint` event triggers after the user clicks the Print button, but there is a Save dialog box. So webpage redirects to the other page before the user completes the full action.

Is there a way to fix this? My current (not working properly) approach is as follows.

PS: My project is written in `React`

```js
  const printDoc = () => {
        const divContents = document.getElementById('printArea').innerHTML;
        const element = window.open('', '', 'height=700, width=1024');
        element.document.write(divContents);
        element.onafterprint = (e) => { // this is where things not work
            console.log(e)
            element.close();
            updatePickListPrintStatus(PRINT_STATUS.SUCCESS);
            redirectAfterPrint()
        }
        getCssFromComponent(document, element.document);
        element.document.close();
        // Loading image lazy
        setTimeout(() => {
            element.print();
        }, 1000);
    };
```

Comment: Good explanation, but at least we should be able to identify eitheruser clicked "Print "or "Close" or print dialog box isn't it? that's because the `element.onafterprint` returns on that dialogbox close?

Comment: `element.print` invokes the windows print dialog box. What I need to know was what action the user performs on that dialog box, which is either "print" or "close". What I thought was, that I can have some kind of feedback from that print dialog box. but it seems there is no such way. regarding the PDF, (and also in many printers), there is another dialog box pops up for some printer specific configs. The issue I'm facing here is if I redirected user to the next page URL before that action completes, it is not good. I'm looking a way to fix that. btw thanks for following up this far

Comment: //all it[browser] can do is trigger system printing thus NO MORE feedback// yeah, the cause is here. Once the browser asks the system to print, that's the end of the story. No more control or feedback other than the close event. As you mentioned in the later comment, yes printing is very dependent on the system and browser so universal feedback is tricky. btw my conclusion is that the current approach is the way to go and the answer to the first question is, "you cannot, at the moment" I guess...